# Laravel with postgresql db cant insert value to table and get last inserted id with eloquent

Tags: php, sql, arrays, laravel, postgresql

Laravel Framework 5.4.36 | psql (PostgreSQL) 11.2

Hi, now I want to migrate my existing Laravel project DB from MySQL into PostgreSQL, I have some trouble here

```
$insert = [
   "a" => "name",
   "b" => age
   .
   .
];


return DB::table('table')->insert($insert);
```

when I try to insert DB with array data it returns like this,

```
Undefined column: 7 ERROR:  column "0" of relation "table" does not exist ..
LINE 1: insert into "table" ("0", "1", "2", ..
```

it not return "a","b","c".. column but array position. with MySQL DB it is working

---

and

i try to get last inserted data id like this,

```
$data = [
   'name'=>$name,
   'address'=>$address,
   'id_class'=>$id_class,
   'lat'=>$lat,
   'long'=>$long,
   'is_changed'=>true
];
return Model::create($data)->id;
```

this will return undefine for id value

---

i update my code, 1st problem already resolved with this:

```
$insert[] = [
   "a" => "name",
   "b" => age
   .
   .
];

foreach(array_chunk($insert,5000) as $i){
  return DB::table('table')->insert($insert);
}
```

Comment: try to do `$model = Model::create($data); return $model->id`

Comment: @Saromase still undefine

Comment: i think you need to define a primary key in the model protected $primaryKey = 'id';

Comment: @AhmedAboud not working too

Comment: So you want to create db table `table` without having defined Model for that table?

Comment: no, i dont create db table, but try to calling model and create data with 'create' eloquent @Alex

Comment: Who should create the table `table` for you in this case? Does it exist in DB?

Comment: @Alex yes when i create model from cmd i use --migration, then  run migrate db

Comment: @iskandarsuhaimi in the model     protected $table = 'your_table';

Answer (score 0):

I once got the same error.
The issue was
Accidentally i put

```
DB::beginTransaction();
```

In my auth middleware, forgot to close the beginTransaction by

```
DB::commit();
```

that is why, every time i try to insert new value, i get the ID but entry doesn't appear in database.